# Javascript behaves differently in Chrome vs. Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-access-security

I am learning how to develop offline chrome app.

I have three components: main.html, main.css, main.js

Main.js is loaded in main.html /html/head/script using this tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

and initial action is triggered by onLoad event in body tag:

```
<body onLoad="initOnLoad(); ">
```

The function initOnLoad() manipulates some elements found by their HTML id:

```
...
1:  function initOnLoad() {
2:     alert("initOnLoad started");
3:     initWaveArray();
4:     addWaveButtons(document.getElementById("wave_selector"));
5:     addBandButtons(document.getElementById("band_selector"));
6:     e = document.getElementById("wave_HF");
7:     activeWaveDiv = e;
8:     setActiveWave();
9:     initDateTime();
10: }
```

Calls in lines 4 and 5 populate some  elements into main.html.

Now, when I load this page in Chrome during development, everything works as expected. But when I load my project as Chrome app, I have these properties in **manifest.json**:

```
"app": {"launch": {"local_path": "main.html"}},
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "main.js", "main.css", "main.html"]
...
```

When I start the app, it loads the page, *initOnLoad()* function is started, but the calls to *document.getElementById()* in lines 4 and 5 produce ***null*** reference and hence nothing is loaded in the HTML document.

Although this obviously seems to be related to security, I cannot find where is my  mistake.

Comment: Can you verify that your "google-chrome-extension" is firing the `onLoad` after the document has loaded. You could try include your `<script>` at the end of the `<body>` removing the `onLoad` and using a self executing function and see if you get the same result.

Comment: I'm guessing we need to see more code--preferably the html, the javascript that calls initOnLoad, and anything else you think is relevant (if the element "wave_selector" is generated by javascript, for example, we probably need to see that).

Comment: What are you suing to build the chrome app?  is an sdk that complies it? more explanation please